# Howe to perform ridge regression only on a subset of the variables

Tags: regression, feature-selection, ridge-regression, regularization

I am trying to code some algorithm that performs ridge-regression with penalty parameter $\lambda$ on all features except for a specific subset.

Let $\mathbf{X}$ be the $n \times p$ matrix for $n$ samples and $p$ features, $\mathbb{y}$ is our vector with the dependent variable for each sample.

If we applied ridge regression with penalization to ALL features, we would have our fit:

$$\mathbf{\hat{y} = X \hat{\beta} = X(X^T X+\lambda I)^{-1}Xy}$$

Nevertheless, what are you supposed to do if you don't want to penalize, say the second feature $p = 2$? Do we just instead of having a constant $\lambda$, let $\lambda^*$ be the penalty for the variables we want to penalize, and then

$$\lambda_i = \begin{cases}\lambda^*, & i \neq 2 \\ 0, & i = 2\end{cases}$$?

Or which way is it supposed to work?

Answer (score 1):

Yes, it is valid to apply different penalties to different coefficients. From the documentation for [glmnet](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/glmnet/):

> penalty.factor: Separate penalty factors can be applied to each
>             coefficient. This is a number that multiplies ‘lambda’ to
>             allow differential shrinkage. Can be 0 for some variables,
>             which implies no shrinkage, and that variable is always
>             included in the model. Default is 1 for all variables (and
>             implicitly infinity for variables listed in ‘exclude’). Note:
>             the penalty factors are internally rescaled to sum to nvars,
>             and the lambda sequence will reflect this change.

Formally you could say this uses $\lambda^*$ where $\lambda^* = a\lambda$ and $a$ is a vector of penalty factors.